# New MacBook but two-facor-auth codes are sent to old one

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-id, big-sur, two-factor-authentication

I bought a new MacBook Pro 2020 and want to retire my MacBook Air 2012.
Since I wanted to start all installations from zero I did not use the migration assistant.
Everything works great. The only problem is that when I access any service with my apple ID, the 6-digit code for authentication gets send to the old computer. In my apple ID settings both computers are listed. How to I change the settings to get the code sent to my new MacBook?

Until having that fixed I would not like to remove the old one from the trusted devices.

Comment: Have you logged into your Apple account and removed that device from your account?

Comment: *ahem*: OP said "Until having that fixed I would not like to remove the old one from the trusted devices." Are you another person that just skims posts and misses out on details? OP also said that they are logged in on both Mac's. Please read posts full next time.

Answer (score -1):

Alright so, go to System Preferences > {your name} (at the top) and click on your new Mac's name at the bottom left, it might be called `XXXX's MacBook Pro` or `MacBook Pro 2020`.

See if there is a trust option if not, tell me and I'll try on my Apple ID.

**Edit**

If the above didn't work, go to System Preferences > {your name} (again, at the top) > Password & Security > Trusted Phone Numbers > Edit > [+] > Enter your Mac's (the Mac you are doing this on, not your old Mac) password > Select country > Enter phone number > Select verify with text message > [Continue] > Enter in verification code > [Continue] > [Done].

This method requires a phone number (and maybe a phone) but then you have a phone to quickly use as a verification method.

**Edit 2**

Alright so I tried this on my Mac's Apple ID but the only option that came up was to add a phone number, I searched it up, found an apple support page about it and it mentioned about going to some Devices section and hitting some trust button.

I am referencing this Apple Support page: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204915#manage

Locate the "View and manage your trusted devices" area on that page.

**Notes/Keep in mind that:**

- Text wrapped in [] means that it is a button.
- Method 2 requires a phone number (and phone, maybe...)

Comment: Alright look, I don't know WHY I got a downvote but at least I tried to help and be useful, alright?